# How to joint Randomly values from cells in excel?

Tags: excel

i have sheet with data i want to joint text from cells in Randomly.

```
 A            B              C              D
Text One      Text Two     Text Three       Text two text one text three
Text name     Text You     Text Me          Text Me Text name Text You
Text 1        Text 2       Text 3           Text 1 Text 3 Text 2
```

I have data in cell A, B, C i want to joint this data in Cell D randomly as above example.

Im new in excel, i tried this `=INDEX($A$2:$B$2:$C$2, RANDBETWEEN(2, 2))` but its not what i want, this formula just pick one randomly value not joint them randomly. Hope you understand my question. Thanks advance.

Comment: What is `RANDBETWEEN(2, 2)` intended to produce?

Comment: At random select one string, then append the random strings to each other. During the random selection of the string there should be a chance of selecting a blank cell at random.

Comment: i just found this formula from internet im new in excel so i cant explain.

Comment: *'its not what i want'* is 1. not a specific problem 2. neither an error code nor an adequate error description 3. No help at all in determining what you are trying to do nor why you are failing at that task.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I interpret your question, you want to create a random concatenation of three cells in the same row. You may want to try

```
=INDEX(A2:C2, RANDBETWEEN(1, 3))&" "&INDEX(A2:C2, RANDBETWEEN(1, 3))&" "&INDEX(A2:C2, RANDBETWEEN(1, 3))
```

Copy the formula down.

Here you see three Index functions, each with a Randbetween() to randomly determine which of the three cells will be used.

The Randbetween() is called three times in the formula. It may produce duplicates or even triplicates of the same number.

Edit: If you want to avoid duplicates, the setup will be a bit more complex.

You will need three helper cells, preferably in the same row. Each helper cell contains the formula `=Rand()` -- not Randbetween!! Rand() is much less likely to produce a duplicate with just three instances.

Next you can use a concatenation of three Index functions where the column argument is constructed with a ranking of the three helper cells.

If the three helper cells are in F1, G1, H1, you can get the numbers 1, 2 and 3 without duplicates, but in random order by using the three formula fragments

```
RANK(F1,$F$1:$H$1)
RANK(G1,$F$1:$H$1)
RANK(H1,$F$1:$H$1)
```

Plug these into three Index functions and concatenate them.

```
=INDEX(A1:C1,RANK(F1,$F$1:$H$1))&" "&INDEX(A1:C1,RANK(G1,$F$1:$H$1))&" "&INDEX(A1:C1,RANK(H1,$F$1:$H$1))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks for help this work , but is their any way to pick unique value . i mean dont  produce duplicates same text .

Comment: Thank You so much for help and your time.